# Слово "Первоначально" - вводное, или нет?

Tags: вводные-слова, пунктуация

"Первоначально технология армирования пола применялась в..." Нужна ли после "Первоначально" запятая?

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Первоначально" - это обычное обстоятельство времени, поэтому никакой запятой здесь не надо

Answer (score 1):

Первоначально -нареч. Запятая не нужна.